# AppEngine Python SDK for Windows fails to run apps with an EOFError

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using Google AppEngine Python SDK for windows on a project, I get the following error when trying to launch an app.

```
2011-09-30 17:20:21 Running command: "['C:\\Python25\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--admin_console_server=', '--port=8086', 'E:\\Programming\\Python\\notepyd']"
    WARNING  2011-09-30 11:51:10,549 urlfetch_stub.py:108] No ssl package found. urlfetch will not be able to validate SSL certificates.
    ERROR    2011-09-30 11:51:15,627 dev_appserver_main.py:644] <type 'exceptions.EOFError'>: 
    2011-09-30 17:21:15 (Process exited with code 1)
```

This happened after a power failure. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start Python and run this:

```
>>> import tempfile
>>> print tempfile.gettempdir()

c:\users\..\appdata\local\temp
```

Go to that directory and delete any files that start with `dev_appserver`.

Answer (score 0):

In your position, I'd be tempted to reinstall Python. You can install a more recent vintage Python (i.e., post-2.5) as long as you don't use any post-2.5 language features or packages.

Comment: I guess I'll have to go with that....
Does Appengine really support python post ver 2.5? 
Their site doesn't say so...

Comment: Did you also install ssl support? From interactive python, does `import ssl` work? If not, you need to install ssl support for python.

Comment: No. The last time I tried installing it from source with MinGW, it failed. Do you know where I could possibly find a pre-compiled binary for win32?

Answer (score 0):

Open:

```
c:\users\{your_pc_name}\appdata\local\temp
```

Delete the directory named:

```
appengine.{your_app_name}
```