# Cant able to run the appliaction on appnegine SDK

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I just tried to run the sample application(gustbook) on google app engine SDK. But it showing warning symbol for that apps.

I have re-insalled both python2.5 & GAE. Still app is not running.

**Here is the Log:-**

```
2011-12-07 11:15:51 Running command: "['C:\\Python25\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--admin_console_server=', '--port=8080', u'C:\\Users\\Nijin\\Documents\\guestbook']"
WARNING  2011-12-07 03:16:00,286 urlfetch_stub.py:111] No ssl package found. urlfetch will not be able to validate SSL certificates.
WARNING  2011-12-07 03:16:02,512 rdbms_mysqldb.py:90] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
ERROR    2011-12-07 03:16:03,213 dev_appserver_main.py:632] <type 'exceptions.EOFError'>: 
2011-12-07 11:16:03 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Screenshot: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7384181/publish/sdk_error.JPG

Comment: Looks like http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3568 in the issue tracker; maybe try deleting the datastore file like the person who posted that issue did? (see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/7614918/110707 )

Comment: Please include the whole stacktrace. We can't help if you cut out the useful parts of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you got invalid characters in one of your strings,
could you give us some code to work with and perhaps some working data?

I'm also guessing you're using the proper urlfetch function and not some home-brew socket solution because that wont work.
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction.html

Try switching to Python 2.7, it's supported and should work better with most libs.
Are you using django-nonrel or something similar?

Comment: I am running the Demo application on GAE SDk(GustBook) and Didn't make any changes in code. And i'm sure that the demo application doesn't use any urlfetch. When try the sample application on Linux it was running fine. So i am sure that there is no error on my application.